# screen capture failed by minimizing remote desktop connection in python

Tags: python-3.x, screenshot, remote-server, pyautogui, rdp

I wrote a script using python, and I want to run it in a server. I use windows remote connection for connecting to this server, but i am facing problem.

I want to run Image Grab for taking screenshot at specific time in day. i am using Pyautogui package for screenshot. But when program is running , an error occurre and program stops execution.

I have the following code, which I am using to capture a screenshot inside a remote desktop (RDP) session.

```
import pyautogui
import time

def imagegrab(): 

    timedata = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M", timedata)
    if (current_time == "10:00"  and current_time == "12:00"):
        
        image=pyautogui.screenshot()
        image.save("box.png")
 
    t = threading.Timer(30.0, imagegrab)
    t.start()
    print("thread calling.")
print(imagegrab())
```

but it throw **OSError: screen grab failed** if remote screen minimize at this time.
how can solve this  problem ? is there is other possible way to capture screen of minimize remote desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem. I would be more than happy if one could provide a solution to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

According to Ranorex Team in [this post](https://www.ranorex.com/forum/running-automation-via-remote-desktop-t1295.html?sid=b6ea38df3a4c4d3f811a3309371731e1#p4699), when a RDP is minimized it is screen locked and the capture cannot be done. The solution provided is to use a VM between your computer and the test computer/server. You connect through RDP to the VM then, from the VM, you connect through RDP to the test computer/server. This way, while you **never** minimize the test computer/server window on the VM you can minimize the VM window on your computer.

I performed a test and it worked without any problem. I will not affirm this solution will work for every situation but is seems to be a good start point.

Notice that the intermediate VM doesn't need to be a killer machine... it just needs to be powerful enough to run RDP.